# Webpack doesn't emit sourcemaps

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I wish I could give more details other than this is the command that I'm invoking:

`node $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --inline --hot -d`

and this is [my webpack config](https://gist.github.com/Birowsky/d03db1083a05e02316a077b7bb5b84fe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all over the docs actually. You just need to provide the `?sourceMap` param after each loader:

`css?sourceMap!postcss?sourceMap!sass?sourceMap`

postcss-loader:

https://github.com/postcss/postcss/blob/master/docs/source-maps.md
https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader

sass-loader:

https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader

css-loader:

https://github.com/webpack/css-loader